# iOS7 Compatibility with Xcode 6

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, xcode6

I want to make my `iOS8` app compatible with `iOS 7.0` but, it gives the following `error` log.

By referring previous questions, I have tried re-adding certain frameworks and making them optional to no avail. Please help me here.

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_CIKernel
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/3F71E632-C303-4C7E-9DA5-BE70B8D2C8FD/xxxxx.app/xxxxx
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
 in /var/mobile/Applications/3F71E632-C303-4C7E-9DA5-BE70B8D2C8FD/xxxxx.app/xxxxx
```

Comment: CIKernel is available in iOS 8.0 and later.  You can not use it when your app is running on iOS 7.x.

Comment: What would be the solution to this? I see that the CoreImage Image framework uses CIKernel, but I'm not sure how to make the same framework backwards compatible.

Comment: Check the availability of the method from the CIKernel class using `respondToSelector`

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `CoreImage.framework` as optional in the **Linked Frameworks and Libraries** section under General Tab.

Comment: Why? `CoreImage` is available from long back and they not yet removed also